# contact form 7 input auto formatting phone (###) ###-####

Tags: user-input, contact-form-7, autoformatting

I want to auto format the user input for phone numbers, Tax-id SSN etc.
for example:

Phone Numbers: no matter how the user will enter the phone number it will automatically format the input as (###) ###-####

Tax ID: ##-#########

SSN: ###-##-####

Currency: automatically add $ and , and . Example 54254.12 will be $54,254.12.
if anyone know how to do it or if there is a plugin that can do that please reply.

Answer (score 0):

For he Phone Numbers I would suggest you to use "International Telephone Input for Contact Form 7" exte